# ext 7 chart proxy data format

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs7

I try to load json data with direct proxy on a cartesian chart in ext 7 like this:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3bae

In this example I load data from ajax but the return data is the same. (its actually copy pasted from my direct api). I have the same result on my testsystem: I can load hardcoded data but not from proxy.

How do I have to format the data so it populates my chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the root property of your JSON must be 'result.data'
2. the data are object, NOT an Array

For yor custom JSON you can write reader transformer, something like this:

```
    ...
    ...
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'test.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            fields: ['month', 'value'], // What is it? 
            transform: {
                fn: function (data) {
                    return Object.values(data.result.data);
                },
                scope: this
            }
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Or you can change the backend to generate standard extjs json, sample:

```
{
    "users": [
       {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Ed Spencer",
           "email": "ed@sencha.com"
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Abe Elias",
           "email": "abe@sencha.com"
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I only had to add the transform to get it working.